# Delay *ngIf statements

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a button on my site, and when I click it this happens:

```
<div class="btn" (click)="toggleStatus=!toggleStatus;>
    <i class="fa-regular fa-plus" *ngIf="!toggleStatus"></i>
    <i class="fa-regular fa-minus" *ngIf="toggleStatus"></i>
</div>
```

So far so good. Fairly simple, and it just changes the icon inside the button depending on the `toggleStatus`. However, when clicking this button, something else on my site happens, which includes some animations. And at least when going back to the default state, I need the icon to not appear right away, but maybe after a few seconds, which will fit perfectly with the other animations.

Is there some way to delay this `*ngIf` change, or is that a big work around ?

Comment: You can create a function, include the `setTimeout` or `timer` and use that function instead of changing `toggleStatus` on the Html page.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1**

use `setTimeout` with fixed time for when the `toggleStatus` will be changed. Does not seem best practice though.

**Solution 2**

If you use angular animations there is an event which is triggered after the animation completes.

Check here for annimation done event  [documentation](https://angular.io/api/animations/AnimationEvent#description)

You can then take that event and emmit a value using an `eventEmmiter`. If your other component listen on changes (has subscribed) on that emmiter you can then change the value of `toggleStatus`. This way you can make sure that the `toggleStatus` changes directly when the animation is completed.

If you provide more information about your problem I will be able to help you more.